# Wcf ria services - custom objects with EF entities - can't compile

Tags: asp.net, silverlight, entity-framework, wcf-ria-services

I have custom entity (not from entity model), which have a property, wich return collection of EF entities (from entity model):

```
[DataContract]
public class MyEntity
{

    [DataMember]
    public List<Role> Roles { get; set; }

}
```

The 'Role' and 'RolePermission' entities are generated by EF4 from DB.
RolePermission has FOREGIN_KEY to Role, and EF4 was generated association between Role and RolePermission:

Role.RolePermissions  --navigate property
  RolePermission.Role   --navigate property

Also, I have DomainService:

```
[EnableClientAccess()]
public class MyEntityService : DomainService
{

    public List<MyEntity> GetMyEntities()
    {
       ...
       myEntityInstance.Roles = <GetRoles>
       ...
       return <collection of MyEntities with Roles>
    }
}
```

When I try to compile this, I get error:

```
Entity 'UserManager.Web.RolePermission' has a property 'RoleReference' with an unsupported type
```

When I put [Include] attribute to MyEntity.Roles property, I get the same error and this error:

```
Property 'Roles' of complex type 'MyEntity' is invalid. Complex types cannot have include members.
```

when I removed reference from RolePermission to Role (RolePermission.Role navigate property) by hands (from entity model), I get only this error in compile time:

```
The Entity 'Role' in DomainService 'RolesService' does not have a key defined. Entity types exposed by DomainService operations must have at least one public property marked with the KeyAttribute.
```

How can I resolve this situation? How can I return my custom object (MyEntity) with filled Roles property from MyEntityService?

A added [key] attr to Role.Metadata, and compile succesfull. But there are no MyEntity.Roles property on the client.

Answer (score 0):

RIA services requires all objects passed back and forth between client to server to have a unique key so it knows which specific object you are modifying.

If you must have your own object as a wrapper for EF objects, just add an id member marked with [key] and maintain that value yourself.

```
[DataContract]
public class MyEntity
{
    [key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public List<Role> Roles { get; set; }

}
```

There seems to be something wrong with the design if you need to do that. What is the parent of a group of roles in your application? Why not just query roles?

Comment: The parent of roles is Application object, which is not stored in database. The Application list I get from IIS. Each application have URL, from which MyAdminApplication can get AppInfo (contrallable objects list, application guid etc). This MyAdminApplication I use to set access rules to users from AD. The AdUser object also don't store in DB, but It should have Roles property.